# UIView is not responsive in ipad - storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, storyboard

I am trying to display the following:

**Already Have Account? Sign in**

Label + Button horizontally, on iPhone devices it is displayed correctly as follow:

[image]

when I run on iPad this is how it looks:

[image]

same problem with the social icons below

I tried to add the elements Label and Button inside a container UIView and I set constraints all directions and chose the arrange option of "Center horizontally in container" but its not fixing the issue, I tried also with Horizontal StackView but also not working for me.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Do you have message in console saying that constraints did broke? Did you set constraint only for some knid of devices? If you use the debug view hierarchy of XCode, what's the frame of the superviews? How did you centered the superviews of the "social"? buttons?

Comment: i have set constraints correctly to all elements but am not sure what you mean by "constraints for some kind of devices?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your screenshots you are having problem with the horizontally stacked views

Instead of a container view you can use **UIStackView** to embed in your *Already have an account?* and *Sign in* Buttons and give **Center horizontally constraint** for the StackView with its SuperView. Also you can add desired spacing between items inside the UIStackView.

You can repeat the same method for the social sign in buttons below also.

Hope this helps!